# Error in testing ng-bootstrap v1.0.0 package:

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to do type head filter with bootstrap package v 1.0.0 because i have
angular 5 and bootstrap 4, like in this site: [https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started][1]

but the problem is that i have this error:

Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngTypeahead' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

my component html file:

```
<label for="typeahead-basic">Search for a state:</label>
<input id="typeahead-basic" type="text" class="form-control"    [(ngModel)]="model" [ngTypeahead]="search"/>

<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

in the ts file :

```
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { UsersService } from '../services/users.service';

 const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado']

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
public model: any;

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
    : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
)
/*************************** */
 ......
```

in app.module.ts:

```
  import { NgbModule, NgbTypeahead, NgbTypeaheadModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 imports[ NgbModule,
 NgbTypeaheadModule.forRoot()]
```

in package.json file:

```
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
 "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.2.0",
 "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
```

thank you for your help

Comment: In your component HTML, I think it should be `[ngbTypeahead]="search"` not `ngTypeahead`

Comment: thanks for your answer Ian, i tried that and it works

Answer (score 0):

the problem is coming from this as Ian a suggested:
think it should be [ngbTypeahead]="search" not ngTypeahead

and it works